# Gets link with searching phrase

Tags: c#, search, web-crawler, html-agility-pack, cpu-word

I am using HtmlAgilityPack and on univerity I had got task to get all links, located next to the word "source" and related. I tried with such a code:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//a[@href]"))
{
    if (document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml.ToString().Contains(sourcesDictionary[i]))
    {
        string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(hrefValue);
    }
}
```

But it just prints all links at HTML Document. What can I change to get it working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the highlighted line may help

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//a[@href]"))
{
**if(link.ParentNode.InnerHtml.Contains("source")**
{
if (document.DocumentNode.InnerHtml.ToString().Contains(sourcesDictionary[i]))
{
    string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(hrefValue);
}
}
}
```